# List directory names using Ansible Find module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to find folder names in `/home/test` directory. Once I have the list of folder names I need to loop over a task. I am able to retrieve the complete path, but not able to retrieve the folder name. is my approach wrong, or is there any easy way to retrieve folder names?

```
--
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    Files: []
    namespaces: []
  tasks:
    - name: Recursively find folders under /home/test
      ansible.builtin.find:
         paths: /home/test
         file_type: directory
         recurse: no
      register: output

    - name: Adding Files to the LIST
      set_fact:
        Files: "{{ Files + [item.path]  }}"
      with_items: "{{ output.files }}"

    - name: Remove the path to only and retrieve folder name only
      set_fact:
        namespaces: "{{ namespaces + item | split('/') | last}}"
      with_items: "{{ Files }}"
```

Error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ namespaces + item | split('/') | last}}): can only concatenate list (not \"str\") to list"}
```

Comment: For [Managing file names and path names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) you may also have a look into filer `| basename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the below declaration into the *vars*

```yaml
namespaces: "{{ output.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list }}"
```

---

**Example of a complete playbook for testing**

Given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
├── dir_A
├── dir_B
├── file_1
└── file_2
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    namespaces: "{{ output.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: /tmp/test
        file_type: directory
      register: output
    - debug:
        var: namespaces
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
namespaces:
  - dir_B
  - dir_A
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `item | split('/') | last` currently returns a string that you try to concatenate to the `namespaces` list. However, this is not allowed and thus you need to cast it to a list as well by simply put it into braces `[]`:

```yaml
    - name: Remove the path to only and retrieve folder name only
      set_fact:
        namespaces: "{{namespaces + [item | split('/') | last]}}"
      with_items: "{{ Files }}"
```